# Python how to set values in a matrix given an array element of which representing the column of the matrix

Tags: python

Suppose I have a N x N matrix M and a N elements array A. A[i] represents M[i, A[i]] entry in M. How do I quickly set corresponding entry in M to value 1 given the array A?

By using numpy so far, what I tried is:
M[0:A.shape[0], A]=1
But this does not work and I don't want to run into a loop which is kind of costy when N is big.

Comment: are you using numpy?

Comment: What have you tried so far and is it not working? Please post your rough work

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask, than use it to set all the values to 1. In this case (for a 4x4 matrix and A=[1,3,2,0]), the mask can be created by:

```
A = np.array([1, 3, 2, 0])
mask = np.zeros((4, 4), int)
np.fill_diagonal(mask, 1)
mask = mask[A, :] > 0
```

Which produces mask:

```
[[False  True False False]
 [False False False  True]
 [False False  True False]
 [ True False False False]]
```

You can then easily apply the mask to a 4x4 matrix `M` and set the corresponding values to 1.

```
np.random.seed(42)
M = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 16).reshape(4, 4)
M[mask] = 1
```

The results is:

```
[[ 0.37454012  1.          0.73199394  0.59865848]
 [ 0.15601864  0.15599452  0.05808361  1.        ]
 [ 0.60111501  0.70807258  1.          0.96990985]
 [ 1.          0.21233911  0.18182497  0.18340451
```

Or you can make it all with a simple for loop, which actually produces the same.

```
A = np.array([1, 3, 2, 0])
np.random.seed(42)
M = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 16).reshape(4, 4)
M[mask] = 1

for i, a in enumerate(A):
    M[i, a] = 1
```